# Call a async function to store accessToken during authentication React-native

Tags: react-native, auth0, asyncstorage

I've created a React-native application, using Auth0 authentication (with the auth code sample below):

```
_onLogin() {
    auth0
        .webAuth
        .authorize({scope: 'openid email', audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'})
        .then(credentials => Alert.alert(
                  'Login Success',
                  'AccessToken: ' + credentials.accessToken,
                  [
                    {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
                  ],
                  { cancelable: false },
                  Actions.home()
                ))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

AND i have this simple function used for store some values into the AsyncStorage (in this case i want store the accessToken given correctly by `credentials.accessToken` in the function above).

```
async _storeSomeValues(item, selectedValue) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, selectedValue);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
```

i've check a lot of post, try many ways to use this function into `.then(...)` statement, but it's always show me this error:

`ReferenceError: _storeSomeValues is not defined`

Why my function is not defined here?

It's my first react-native application, i never coded with react before.

Comment: Where do you call `_storeSomeValues`?

Comment: I don't really know how to call my `_storeSomeValues` function into my 
   .then(...) statement .

I've tried many ways to call it, but it's always show me errors.

Comment: I've find issue, i just need to declare _onLogin function like an arrow function.

`_onLogin = () => {   //..  }`

Then i can call `_storeSomeValues` like `this._storeSomeValues(params....)`

Answer (score 0):

If your `_storeSomeValues` is in another file, you have to export it from your file and then import it in another one.

First in `file1.js`

```
export async function _storeSomeValues(item, selectedValue) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, selectedValue);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }
```

And then in your `file2.js`

```
import { _storeSomeValues } from 'path/to/file1.js';
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your file. Do this each time you want to use `_storeSopeValues()` in another file.

Comment: My `_storeSomeValues` function is in the same file as the `_onLogin` function.